# How to change element top border color in component through props using Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-props

I'm trying to change the color of the top border by passing the color value as props to the component, but It doesn't make any effects.

I'm looking for a solution. Please help me!

```
export default function TargetsProgressInfo(props) {
    return (

            <ul>
                <span className={` after:border-[7px] after:w-4 ${props.colorTip} after:border-b-transparent`}></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div >

    )
}


**home.jsx**

<TargetsProgressInfo colorTip="after-border-t-red-600"/>
```

Comment: Don't use string interpolation or dynamically make class names, Tailwind won't find and generate them. "Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full" https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: Thanks a lot , that helped me to solve the problem .

Comment: Glad it helped, and thanks for posting your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pass the whole name of Tailwind CSS as props

```
        <TargetsProgressInfo colorTip="after:border-t-red-600"/>
```